# BinarySearch returning index of where it belongs

Tags: c++, sorting, binary-search-tree

So i am looking to write a code to return the index that the key is or if it is not there, where it should be. what am i missing ?
min is 0, max is size - 1, buf is sorted

```
int binarySearch(string buf[], string key, int min, int max){

int mid;
while (max >= min){
    mid = (min + max) / 2;

    if (buf[mid] < key)
        min = mid + 1;
    else if (buf[mid] > key)
        max = mid - 1;

    else
        return mid;

}
return min;
}
```

Comment: yea it doesn't work, it doesn't return the right index when the string doesn't exist.

Comment: There is no "right" index if the string is not present. Just how exactly are you planning on disseminating the information that the returned index is where it "should" be vs. where it "is" ? Dereference through that index and compare ? And that buys you ...? The odorous nature of this question is almost overpowering as [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That said, you can do this easily with [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) in about 3 lines of code (roughly).

Comment: True it's just as cheap to do a binary search and if it isn't present do a linear insertion, since you need to shift all the elements anyway to get it into the correct position.

Comment: `long idx = (std::lower_bound(buf+min, buf+max+1, key) - buf);` should do it.

Comment: well this binary search is used by two other methods : find and insert. insert calls binarysearch and the index is always either the index of a duplicate or address where the string should be inserted to keep list sorted. for find you simply check if buf[index] == string we are looking for .

Answer (score 3):

I had practically the same problem, so I wrote this generic code (maybe you may want to use a different namespace than std ;) ) The code below returns the an iterator to the largest element in the sequence which is smaller than or equal to val. It uses O(N log N) time for N = std::difference(first, last), assuming O(1) random access on [first ... last).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace std {

template<class RandomIt, class T>
RandomIt binary_locate(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, const T& val) {
  if(val == *first) return first;
  auto d = std::distance(first, last);  
  if(d==1) return first;
  auto center = (first + (d/2));
  if(val < *center) return binary_locate(first, center, val);
  return binary_locate(center, last, val);
}  

}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> values = {0, 0.5, 1, 5, 7.5, 10, 12.5};
    std::vector<double> tests = {0, 0.4, 0.5, 3, 7.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13};
    for(double d : tests) {
        auto it = std::binary_locate(values.begin(), values.end(), d);
        std::cout << "found " << d << " right after index " << std::distance(values.begin(), it) << " which has value " << *it << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Source: http://ideone.com/X9RsFx

The code is quite generic, it accepts std::vectors, std::arrays and arrays, or any sequence that allows random access. The assumption (read precondition) is that val >= *first and that the values [first, last) are sorted, like needed for std::binary_search.

Feel free to mention bugs or malpractices that I have used.

Answer (score 1):

```
int binary_srch_ret_index(ll inp[MAXSIZE], ll e, int low, int high) {

    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    }

    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if (e == inp[mid]) {
        return mid;
    }

    if (e < inp[mid]) {
        return binary_srch(inp, e, low, mid - 1);
    } else {
        return binary_srch(inp, e, mid + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You searched for a character and you assumed that charaters in the buf are sorted.

If you want to search for a string use a string match pattern algorithm. 
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

If you want to search a character or a number in an ordered array then see this:
http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-binary-search

Answer (score 0):

In binary search you can do value type search not reference type. If you want to search for string in string array you have to write a complex program or use has table

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do this. its just a logical error, i can't get the algorithm right.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int binarySearch(int buf[], int key, int min, int max);

    int main()
{
    int data[] = {1,2,4,6,7,9};

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        int result = binarySearch(data, data[i], 0, 5);
        assert(result == i);
    }

    assert(binarySearch(data, 3, 0, 5) == 1);
    assert(binarySearch(data, 5, 0, 5) == 2);
    assert(binarySearch(data, 8, 0, 5) == 4);
    assert(binarySearch(data, 10, 0, 5) == 5);

    return 0;
}



int binarySearch(int buf[], int key, int min, int max)
{
    int mid;
    while (max >= min){
        mid = (min + max) / 2;

        if (buf[mid] < key)
            min = mid + 1;
        else if (buf[mid] > key)
            max = mid - 1;

        else
            return mid;

    }
    return std::min(min, max);
}
```

Comment: The function needs to return the index that the comparing key should be placed, not just find if its in there.. so can't return -1

Comment: Will fix, gimme a few secs

Comment: There, those tests pass at least. Added a test for -3, returns -1 so that seems to work as well. The index number it returns is the number it should be after, or the number it is.

Comment: for some reason it still doesn't work properly.! thanks for the help tho